# How to flip a column of ratios, convert into a fraction and convert to a float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
         Date Ratio
0  2000-06-21   4:1
1  2000-06-22   3:2
2  2000-06-23   5:7
3  2000-06-24   7:1
```

For each item in the `Ratio` column, I want to reverse the ratio, convert it into a fraction and convert it to a float.

Meaning 4:1 would become 1:4, then the : would be replaced with a / and finally it would get 0.25. 3:2 would become 2/3 which is converted to 0.66666666666.

So far I only have the following code:

```
df['Ratio'] = df['Ratio'].str.split(":")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create new `DataFrame` with `expand=True` in [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), convert to integers and last divide columns:

```
df1 = df['Ratio'].str.split(":", expand=True).astype(int)
df['Ratio'] = df1[1].div(df1[0])
```

For one line solution is possible use [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
df['Ratio'] = (df['Ratio'].str.split(":",expand=True)
                          .astype(int)
                          .set_axis(['a','b'], inplace=False, axis=1)
                          .eval('b/a'))
print (df)
         Date     Ratio
0  2000-06-21  0.250000
1  2000-06-22  0.666667
2  2000-06-23  1.400000
3  2000-06-24  0.142857
```

Comment: wow that was fast, thanks. it works, will accept your answer in 12 mins.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
df['Ratio'] = df['Ratio'].apply(lambda x: 1 / eval(x.replace(':', '/')))
```

Or:

```
df['Ratio'] = 1 / df['Ratio'].str.replace(':', '/').apply(eval)
```

Or as commented by @anky_91, `pd.eval` also works:

```
df['Ratio'] = 1 / pd.eval(df['Ratio'].str.replace(':', '/'))
```

Comment: i was about to post this alternative but with `pd.eval` : `1/pd.eval(ser.str.replace(':','/'))` -safer than eval :)

Comment: this is a great answer as well, because i don't have to create new frames

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your own function, for example this one:

```
def get_new_ratio(ratio):
    ratio_splitted = list(map(int, ratio.split(':')))
    return ratio_splitted[1] / ratio_splitted[0]
```

And after that use it as an argument in [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
>>> df['new_ratio'] = df.Ratio.apply(get_new_ratio)
>>> print(df)
         Date Ratio  new_ratio
0  2000-06-21   4:1   0.250000
1  2000-06-22   3:2   0.666667
2  2000-06-23   5:7   1.400000
3  2000-06-24   7:1   0.142857
```